# Setting a MySql session variable for every single connection in a pool

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core

I'm connecting to MySql using mysqlconnector.net (https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/) and want to set some session variables for every single session: `SET SESSION wait_timeout = 60` and `SET SESSION information_schema_stats_expiry = 15`. I would like to always set these session variables, but not have the overhead of executing an additional query when a pooled connection is used (since it's a game server and throughput matters). The user does not have permission to set global variables.

I understand session variables are valid for the lifetime of a `MySqlConnection` object, and if the connection is created with the `ConnectionReset = false` option, then session variables will persist when the connection is pooled.

The problem: I don't know whether a connection is being truly created or is coming from the pool, since the same constructor can do either. I would like to set the session variables only when the connection is new.

One solution I can see is to modify the MySql connection library to add an API that would tell me whether a connection object has been newly created or was taken from the pool.

The workaround I will be using is to set the global variables when the DB is created using Ansible--the [mysql_variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/mysql_variables_module.html) module seems to do what I need (actually since I'm using AWS it'll have to be the [rds_param_group](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/rds_param_group_module.html) module), however this question is still valid, since there are other MySql users that are not in control of the database they're using.

Comment: I think your use case is specialised enough that you might want to use `Pooling=false` in the connection string and implement your own custom connection pool on top of MySqlConnector.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger I'm surprised wanting to set system variables without extra performance cost is so specific. But that's a good idea. I'd consider making that an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A request similar to yours has already been discussed at https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/issues/519, with an answer similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42592101/23633): attach an event handler to `MySqlConnection.StateChange` to set the session variables.

If your performance needs are such that you cannot incur the overhead of resetting the session (the default behaviour of `ConnectionReset=true`) and setting the session variables each time, then it might make sense to implement your own connection pool.

By setting `Pooling=false;` in the connection string, MySqlConnector's pooling will be bypassed and calling `MySqlConnection.Open(Async)` will immediately open a new connection. You would have to keep the connection open and not Close/Dispose it (which might impose an awkward programming pattern), or wrap it in an `IDisposable` wrapper that returns it to your custom pool.